# Free Like&Dislike Wordpress Plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

i search a **free** ***like & dislike*** **wordpress plugin** (for post,comment,page...), that give a possibility to **copy and paste a *shortcode* of plugin and place it any where in ours comments or pages** ..... (FREE PLUGIN)
thanks you

Comment: What actually you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Try this :**

Plugin I found :

> [LINK](https://wordpress.org/plugins/vd-likes/installation/)

**Shortcode :**

```
[vd_likes id='POST_ID']
```

This is for page or post. Replace **POST_ID** and add post/page id.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try [WTI Like Post](https://wordpress.org/plugins/wti-like-post/) with much more downloads and options.